# How to change the font size using execCommand

Tags: javascript, html, document, font-size, execcommand

I am having a style for font in my htm file
`FONT{
font-size:11px;
}`
which will be loaded initially when my htm loads
Now I would like to change the font-size using the following command
 `document.execCommand("fontsize", "", "5");`
After execution 
Now the font tag consists of the attribute size = "5"
But I could see font-size:11px still in Current styles of IE Developer toolbar. So the font is not changed.

How to change the font size
Please help.

Comment: See this [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868295/document-execcommand-and-fontsize-in-pixels

Answer (score 0):

This may be late, but I suggest trying `document.execCommand('fontsize,false,'5').` In some browsers, not passing `false` to defaultUI (the second argument) results in the command not running.

What does it return when you run it? `execCommand` will return `true/false` based on success or failure.