# document.execCommand() FontSize in pixels?

Tags: javascript, editor, execcommand

How can I change font size to 30px (for example) using `document.execCommand`?

This:

```
document.execCommand("fontSize", false, "30px");
```

doesn't work, because in 3rd argument of the function execCommand, it only allows me to input a value between and including 1 to 7.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a limitation of the `FontSize` command. There are various options I can think of:

- You could use a CSS class instead and use the [CSS class applier](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) module of my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library;
- You could use a hacky method, such as calling `document.execCommand("fontSize", false, "7");` and then finding the elements the command has created and changing them as required. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/S3ctN/. This obviously depends on there being no other `<font>` elements with size 7 in the document and it also relies on the browser using `<font>` elements for font size, which it seems they all do.

Answer (score 11):

**Function**

```
var execFontSize = function (size, unit) {
    var spanString = $('<span/>', {
        'text': document.getSelection()
    }).css('font-size', size + unit).prop('outerHTML');

    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, spanString);
};
```

**Execute**

```
execFontSize(30, 'px');
```

Comment: This works in mozilla firefox, but doesn't work in ie

Comment: It removes any other HTML/CSS within the selection!

Answer (score 9):

Just override it with css:

```
font[size='7']{
    font-size: 20px; // or other length unit
}
```

Or if you use scss you could use a loop to generate all selectors from 1 to 7:

```
@for $i from 1 to 7 {
    font[size='#{$i}']{
        font-size: $i * 2vw
    }
}
```

Comment: Very simple and nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

As second answer suggest just run some jquery after execcommand and replace the markup with your own.

Just replace elem with your element and edit the font-size with the desired value.

```
jQuery("font[size]", elem).removeAttr("size").css("font-size", "10px");
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a better solution than many proposed here, as it directly gets the element on which to change the font size from the selected text.

As a consequence, it doesn't have to browse the DOM to get the right element, and doesn't require to ban the use of a specific fontSize (7, as suggested in the first option of the accepted answer, and in other answers).

```
function changeFont() {
    document.execCommand("fontSize", false, "7");
    var fontElements = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode
    fontElements.removeAttribute("size");
    fontElements.style.fontSize = "30px";
}
```

In summary we just use execCommand to wrap the selection with a span, so that the subsequent call to getSelection() whill have the highlighted span as parent . Then we just add the fontSize style to that identified span.

Here, as we are using the fontSize command, it won't be wrapped inside a `<span>`, but inside a `<font>`.

But this is a generic method which can work with any command of execCommand, the latter being used just as a convenient manner to wrap the selected contents even among different elements.

Here is a live [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5vL8tz62/2/)

Comment: Does it work well with editor undo/redo? I tried cursorily and it works.

Comment: Yes, it easily feasible, you just have to replace the span(s) (or font(s) in this case) by its/their content (innerHTML). Let's say you have <font style="font-size: 40px;">m</font>, you just have to replace it the innerHTML or innerText, i.e. "m"

Comment: Glad I helped ;)

Answer (score 5):

it just my solutions.it works with chrome.
the code was find in a china website(eqxiu).

first

```
document.execCommand("styleWithCSS", 0, true);
document.execCommand('fontSize', 0, '12px');
```

then

```
jQuery.find('[style*="font-size: -webkit-xxx-large"],font[size]').css("font-size", "12px")
```

note:
the fontsize pass to execCommand must be at least '12px' and above.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much.

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(()=>{
 var activeFontSize = 30;
 var oDoc = document.getElementById("editor");
 var style = document.createElement("style");
 document.body.appendChild(style);
 
 function setFontSize(value){
  $editor.focus();
  document.execCommand("fontsize", false, 20);
  activeFontSize = value;
  createStyle();
  updateTags();
 }

 function updateTags(){
  var fontElements = oDoc.getElementsByTagName("font");
  for (var i = 0, len = fontElements.length; i < len; ++i) {
   if (fontElements[i].size == "7") {
    fontElements[i].removeAttribute("size");
    fontElements[i].style.fontSize = activeFontSize+"px";
   }
  }
 }

 function createStyle(){
  style.innerHTML = '#editor font[size="7"]{font-size: '+activeFontSize+'px}';
 }

 function updateToolBar(args){
  $fontSize.val(args.fontsize);
 }

 var $fontSize = $("#fontSize");
 var $editor = $("#editor");

 $fontSize.on("change", ()=>{
  setFontSize($fontSize.val())
 })

 $editor.on("keyup", ()=>{
  updateTags();
 })

 //var i = 0;
 $editor.on("keyup mousedown", (e)=>{
  //i++;
  //console.log("e.target", e.target)
  try{
   var fontsize = $(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer.parentNode).css("font-size")
   fontsize = fontsize.replace("px", "");
   //document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, '<span class="font-size-detector'+i+'">X</span>');
   //var fontsize = $(e.target).css("font-size")//$editor.find(".font-size-detector"+i).css("font-size");
   //document.execCommand("undo", false, false);
   //$editor.focus();
   //console.log("fontsize", fontsize)
   updateToolBar({fontsize})
  }catch(e){
   console.log("exception", e)
  }
 })

 oDoc.focus();
 setFontSize(30);
})
```

```css
.editor-box{box-shadow:0px 0px 1px 2px #DDD;max-width:500px;margin:0px auto;}
  .editor-tools{padding:20px;box-shadow:0px 2px 1px 0px #DDD}
  .editor-tools button{user-select:none;}
  #editor{height:200px;margin:10px 0px;padding:10px;font-size:14px;}
  #editor:focus{outline:none}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editor-box">
 <div class="editor-tools">
  <label>Font Size: </label>
  <select id="fontSize" >
   <option value="10">10px</option>
   <option value="12">12px</option>
   <option value="14">14px</option>
   <option value="20">20px</option>
   <option value="22">22px</option>
   <option value="30" selected="true">30px</option>
   <option value="35">35px</option>
   <option value="40">40px</option>
   <option value="45">45px</option>
   <option value="50">50px</option>
  </select>
 </div>
 <div id="editor" contenteditable="true">Hello, this is some editable text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution in pure JavaScript that works for multiple lines with custom HTML (colors, font families).

Get the selection of the document. Parse the selection and save the html tags from it. Then with document.execCommand insert the selected html inside a div that has inline style. Also a benefit when using document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, html) is that you get undo in WYSIWYG editor.

This is the function:

```
function fontSize(size) {

    var sel = document.getSelection(); // Gets selection

    var selectedHtml = "";
    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        var container = document.createElement("div");
        for (var i = 0, len = sel.rangeCount; i < len; ++i) {
            container.appendChild(sel.getRangeAt(i).cloneContents());
        }
        const children = container.getElementsByTagName("*")
        for(let child of children) {
            if(child.style.fontSize) {
                child.style.fontSize = `${size}px`
            }
        }
        selectedHtml = container.innerHTML;
    }

    let html = `<div style="font-size: ${size}px;">${selectedHtml}</div>`
    document.execCommand('insertHTML', false, html);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

best solution i've seen

```
function onFS() {
const size = prompt("Enter font size:")
const txt = document.getSelection()

document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, `<font style=font-size:${size}px;>${txt}</font>`)
}
```

Comment: This works but it removes all other stuff, that is applied on the text. Stuff like font-family is not applied anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have had exactly the same problem. The answer from surinder singh helped me, but it was more code than necessary and made it really complicated. Also, it's made with jQuery, I only work with React and TypeScript. So here is the TypeScript Version:

```
const targetFontSize = 24;

// @ts-ignore
document.execCommand('fontSize', false, 20);

let style = document.getElementById('editor-styler');
if(!style) {
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.id = 'editor-styler';
    document.head.appendChild(style);
}

style.innerHTML = '#editor font[size="7"] { font-size: ' + targetFontSize + 'px}';

const fontElements = document.getElementsByTagName('font');
for(let fontElement of Array.from(fontElements)) {
    const font = fontElement as HTMLElement;
    if(font.getAttribute('size') !== '7') continue;
    font.removeAttribute('size');
    font.style.fontSize = targetFontSize + 'px';
}
```

This solution also keeps track on other changes on the text, for e.g. font-family changes.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set the default font size for the editor then this is what you can do.

You have to configure the TinyMCE CSS using the `content_style` options.

For example, the following configuration will set the default font size to 12pt.

```js
tinymce.init({
  /* ... */ content_style: "body {font-size: 12pt;}",
});
```

Just remember, these styles are specific to the content inside the editor - if you want it to be the default size on the published content too, you’ll have to make sure the same style is applied to those published pages.

Hope it helps.