# Javascript: execcommand fontsize in px

Tags: wysiwyg, font-size, execcommand

all.. I do know that this question is kind of scattered over the internet, but nothing seems to be pointing me right.

I am making my own wysiwyg and the problem I'm facing is that the code

```
document.execCommand("fontSize", false, value);
```

accepts only values from 1 to 7 (inclusive) to be assigned to the "size" attribute of "font" tag. However I need to set the font-size in *pixels*.

I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/S3ctN/55/) example in a similar [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868295/document-execcommand-and-fontsize-in-pixels). But the problem with this approach is that it only changes the font-size for the selected text. if you aim to set the font-size before typing your text, it will not work.

Does any one have any idea how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hacky method, such as calling `document.execCommand("fontSize", false, "7");` and then finding the elements the command has created and changing them as required. See example: http://jsfiddle.net/S3ctN/.

This obviously depends on there being no other  elements with size 7 in the document and it also relies on the browser using  elements for font size, which it seems they all do

[document.execCommand() FontSize in pixels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868295/document-execcommand-fontsize-in-pixels)