# wysiwyg - execCommand changing font and font size properly with HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, text-formatting

I'm making my own WYSYWIG. I use execCommand and I have a problem with it.

There is a lot of tutorials on how to make a WYSIWYG.

When I change the font size or font type, my script generates code with  tag.  is outdated.

This is a very simple WYSIWYG like many you can find in tutorials. There is an iframe with onload function:

```
function loadIframe()
{
    document.getElementById('text-iframe').contentWindow.document.designMode = 'on';
}
```

And some buttons with onclick functions used to format the text.

This is the function I use for changing the font size:

```
function changeFontsize()
{
    var size = document.getElementById('fontsizeSelect').value;
    document.getElementById('text-iframe').contentWindow.document.execCommand('FontSize', false, size);
}
```

Other functions are pretty similar and use the same execCommand method, so I think I don't have to show them to you.

The code my WYSIWYG generates looks like this:

```
<font color="red" face="Verdana" size="5">test</font>
```

And my question is: How to make my WYSIWYG generate a modern code proper with HTML5? As it should be coded now, not with outdated  tags.

Comment: you have to write your own javascript code to change them, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868295/document-execcommand-fontsize-in-pixels

Comment: I will just leave it as it is and write a function that changes every <font> into <span> and it will be ok. Generating the html as it is and then editing the string looks most ok for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you issue this statement once:

```
   document.execCommand( 'styleWithCSS', true )
```

then the code will generate something like:

```
<span style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: x-large;">test</span>
```